# How I can create small buttons in a LinearLayout dynamically creating a line break when you touch the edge of this?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I am trying to create buttons dynamically in one LinearLayout which is in a ExpandibleListView (then it is an adapter), my situation is that when I create a button they occupy the entire width of the screen that can be only 1, but I like to have several buttons depending on only one line of text in each button

My Situation:
[image]

I need:

[image]

My xml is the follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/sub_sub_sub_itemes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my code java is:

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final OptionItemPromo entry = (OptionItemPromo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition); 
    final String childText = entry.getTitle();


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_sub_sub_itemes);
    ll.removeAllViews();
    int _width_so_far = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < entry.getSelection_items().size(); i++){

         final LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         final Button myButton = new Button(this._context);
         myButton.setText(entry.getSelection_items().get(i).getName());
         myButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4d4d4d"));
         myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dedede"));
         myButton.setTextSize(16);
         ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }



    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: google for: android flow layout

Answer (score 1):

set `singleLine` to `true` using  `setSingleLine()` metod so that the button's text don't take more than one line and `setEllipsize` at the `End` so that if text of button have multiple line then it places **Dot (.)** at the end. add these two line with your button...

```
    myButton.setSingleLine(true);
    myButton.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

Comment: ``TextUtils.TruncateAt.END``  This function is not recognized

Comment: press...`ctr+shift+O` **OR** `import android.text.TextUtils;`

Comment: My question is: Will either using a LinearLayout with "orientation = vertical" option?. I say this because the elements are located down